# Grepping serial port data flow in Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, grep, serial-port

In Linux I can filter incoming serial port data:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 | grep somestring
```

Now I am trying to do the same in Windows

```
type com1 | findstr somestring
```

This command not even does not find the searched string, it also finishes and does not do filtering continuously.

**The task is to try to do this using only built-in Windows features without downloading and installing any tools.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *PowerShell*'s `select-string` for that:

```
type com1 | select-string -pattern "somestring"
```

---

For example:

```
ipconfig | select-string -pattern "IPv4"
```

outputs a list of your IPv4 addresses only:

> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.199
>   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1

---

**To further elaborate (for others):**
If you have PowerShell 3.0 installed, you can use the `sst` alias to invoke `select-string`.